# How to flip an IplImage

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there an easy non costly method to flip an IplImage along the y-axis ?
I'm working with high framerates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `cvFlip` (see [Operation On Arrays](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html)) that can do in place flipping. Horizontal, vertical and combined flipping is supported.

**Example: Flipping y-axis:**

```
cvFlip(Image, NULL, 1);
```

Comment: thanx, i did not see that it works with ipl image as well. my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use C++ API `Mat`? Try this out and see if it works with your requirement. Just replace `IplImage* img` with your frame.

```
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("c:\\test.jpg");
cvFlip(img, img, 0);
cvNamedWindow("result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
cvShowImage("result", img);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("result");
```